# Does category theory help in operator algebras?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

I'm currently studying the basics of Banach and $C^*$-algebras. Almost all the proofs i've seen so far are **very simple** but some of them are **extremely tricky** (in my opinion). This tricky interplay between the bits of analysis and algebra make some of the proofs seem unilluminating and disconnected from the flow of the theory.

**Is there an approach to operator algebras that uses category theory to simplify and "trivilize" the elementary theory?**

Ideally it would use input from analysis (category of banach spaces, hilbert spaces, topological vector spaces) and algebra (category of associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ for a start) only when absolutely (and obviously) necessary.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Better?

Comment: So are you asking if more advanced math will make current math easier to understand/solve?

Comment: @Alizter In what sense is category theory more advanced than operator algebras? Are categories more advanced than homological algebra? or commutative algebra? Even though it's entirely self contained while the other are not?

Comment: @SaalHardali Well I didn't understand the wording of your question so I asked a question. I take it thats' not what you want.

Comment: First -1 I got on MSE (not to mention 4 close votes). I wonder what's wrong with this question...

Comment: It might help if you gave a specific example of a "trivial" fact in operator algebras which you want to see as "trivially trivial". People may also not realize that you're referencing a famous quote by Peter Freyd, along the lines of "Perhaps the aim of category theory is to see that the trivial is trivially trivial".

Comment: The thing is that things in category theory tend to include an identity element by definition, but much interesting operator algebra takes place in rings without identity. There is probably a lot one can translate if one is careful, though.

Comment: @tcamps, actually Barry Mitchell according to https://books.google.es/books?id=STc4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22trivially+trivial%22.&source=bl&ots=J8XMI--lco&sig=mt-KPTOan8iJNJ5eJPUdDMqDXn4&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0vczOh7bLAhVHuhQKHeZbARMQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22trivially%20trivial%22.&f=false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I cannot give an authoritative answer that such an approach does not exist, it would really surprise me if it did.

That "tricky interplay" between algebra and analysis is precisely what makes operator algebras interesting. In particular, the close relation between an algebraic notion (the spectral radius) and a topological one (the norm) is at the cornerstone of the theory. Every key theorem uses that interplay in a very smart (rather than "tricky") way.